# scala RDD dataprocess

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

this is my code:

```
val data = Array("eq_len Alice@TF [11.5, 11.8, 12.0, 12.3, 12.56, 12.79, 13.01, 16.85] 639684 16.4 11.565149",
                 "eq_len Bob@TY [0.0, 2.4, 4.8, 7.2, 9.6, 12.0, 14.4, 16.8] 604804 48.0 0.0",
                 "eq_len Cool@GF [11.4, 12.35, 13.3, 14.25, 15.2, 16.15, 17.1, 18.05] 639677 0.184546 0.003718",
                 "eq_len Gop@FF [ 7.6, 8.55, 9.5, 10.45, 13.2, 13.9, 14.6, 15.3] 629981 0.585282 0.000504")
val sc = prepareConfig();
val baseRDD = sc.parallelize(data)
```

and i want this result:

```
Alice,11.5, 11.8, 12.0, 12.3, 12.56, 12.79, 13.01, 16.85
Bob,0.0, 2.4, 4.8, 7.2, 9.6, 12.0, 14.4, 16.8
Cool,11.4, 12.35, 13.3, 14.25, 15.2, 16.15, 17.1, 18.05
Gop,7.6, 8.55, 9.5, 10.45, 13.2, 13.9, 14.6, 15.3
```

thanks.

Comment: So your question is different from this one you have asked before http://stackoverflow.com/q/40605461/3415409 how ? Please put some effort in your question and read about how to ask question on SO! It's not a homework platform

Answer (score 0):

this is my code:

```
val rdds = sc.textFile(filename)

val sets = rdds.map{
  line => val splt = line.split("\t")
    val spltflag = "\\w+".r
    val id = spltflag findFirstIn splt(1) match {
      case Some(y) => y
    }
    (id,splt(2))
}
```

Comment: Edit the qiestion, don't add this (non-) answer. As @eliasah says, read some of the (quite good) help on how to ask questions here